# Can't resolve overloaded method with generic lambda

Tags: java, java-8

This code:

```
public static void f(String[] args)  {}
public static void f(Integer[] args)  {}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    f(Stream.of("xxx").toArray(i -> new String[i]));
}
```

compiles success with jdk8u45 but jdk8u60 prints the following error:

```
Error:(17, 9) java: reference to f is ambiguous
  both method f(java.lang.String[]) in type_infer.Test and method f(java.lang.Integer[]) in type_infer.Test match
```

Does it follow the JSL, Why compiler can not resolve overloaded methods? Was it a fixed bug in jdk8u45?

Comment: More info: compiles fine in javac 1.8.0_25, 1.8.0_40, ecj 3.10.2; fails with the same message in javac 1.9.0-ea-b72. More interesting is that replacing `i -> new String[i]` with `String[]::new` fixes the problem in javac 1.9.0-ea-b72.

Comment: i believie it is fixed, i tried it in ideone, and it is using sun jdk 8u51 here is link http://ideone.com/wvCXyO

Comment: And with jdk1.8.0_60 replacing i -> new String[i] with String[]::new doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Changing `i -> new String[i]` to `String[]::new` fixes the problem and so does `(int i) -> new String[i]` so at least there is a recognizable pattern…

Comment: @assylias I download the lastest jdk8u60 for linux and can reproduce it from command line.

Comment: @assylias I downloaded jdk8u60x64 for Windows (7) and I got the same error message

Comment: @And390 You are right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug recently introduced in `javac`.

The argument in the call to `f(..)` is clearly of type `String[]`.
This can, e.g., be shown by resolving the same expression as a standalone expression:

```
String s1 = Stream.of("xxx").toArray(i -> new String[i])[0];
String[] s2 = Stream.of("xxx").toArray(i -> new String[i]).clone();
```

These **are** accepted by all versions of compilers.

Clearly, `f(Integer[])` is not applicable with an argument of type `String[]`. I see no reason why the outer type inference would force the inner resolution to a worse result (e.g., `Object[]`) than resolution as a standalone expression.

Additional evidence: the following statement is correctly rejected even by those versions of `javac` affected by this bug:

```
Integer[] s3 = Stream.of("xxx").toArray(i -> new String[i]);
```

Hence `f(Integer[])` is clearly out of the reckoning.

Comment: 2022, and this bug is still in `javac`. Do you know whether there’s a related bug report?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the pain from a known bug in the jvm
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8029718
Not sure how to relate the "fixed version" to the builds available at Oracle website.
But anyway you should work in the latest version and report your findings in that bug. Maybe they fixed it and now there is a regression.

Comment: A jvm bug wouldn't explain the compile error, but the bug you cite is actually assigned to javac. OTOH, that bug was fixed for 8u20 so the fix *is* available in all versions mentioned in the question plus comments.