# inference variable R has incompatible bounds

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, javac, compiler-bug

Today i experienced a strange error. The Strange was if i add the below code block in eclipse IDE it shows no error , but the same piece of code i compile it from cmd its showing error as

**inference variable R has incompatible bounds**

The Code Piece as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,1,4,65,3,56,24};
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(x).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.counting())));
    }
}
```

I Used same JDK versions(**11.0.15 2022-04-19 LTS**) both in eclipse as well as cmd prompt to compile it. Is Eclipse is doing some magic here or it is a bug at eclipse IDE.

Comment: Java 19 javac still complains. Strangely moving the code out of the println and assigning to a variable makes it work. Note that Eclipse uses its own compiler which is why you may ocassionally get different results.

Comment: The problem is that `println` is overloaded. So it’s the same bug as in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32223890/2711488). Introduced somewhere around Java 8, update 60.